# xdebug: Don't get rid of machine name as xdebug.idekey

Tags: netbeans, xdebug, httpd.conf, php

I am fighting to get xdebug working with my Apache 2.x, PHP 5.3 and my Netbeans 6.9:

I got to the point that everything looks good in phpinfo, except:

```
local value         local value     master value
xdebug.idekey   MYTHINKPAD$ netbeans-xdebug
```

MYTHINKPAD is the name of my local (Windows 7x64) machine.
I don't have the faintest clue, where the master value gets overriden in such way.
Certainly no php_value in http.conf nor .htaccess, nor anything unusual in php.ini:

```
xdebug.remote_host=localhost
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.idekey="netbeans-xdebug"
```

What's even more suprising, if I add this to httpd.conf, restart and look at phpinfo():

```
This has an effect (no surprise) and shows in phpinfo():
php_value iconv.output_encoding "UTF-8"
This has an effect (no surprise) and shows in phpinfo():
php_value xdebug.max_nesting_level 111
Again, sigh, my machine name 'wins'...
php_value xdebug.idekey foobardoo
```

Huh? Can somebody fill me in, why my machine name is so resilient?

While at it, what `AllowOverride` would allow me to use php_value statements in .htaccess files? (yes, I googled). Or not possible at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know nothing about the reasons.
But a fix is to define a global environment variable:

```
DBGP_IDEKEY     netbeans-xdebug(orwhatever)
```

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be an xdebug bug that was fixed in 2.1.4 / 2.2.0

http://bugs.xdebug.org/bug_view_page.php?bug_id=00000758